# Android AIDL Service is creating new processes

Tags: android, android-service, aidl, android-service-binding

I was under the impression that if I have an AIDL service in my application every new interface instance would be connected to the same application process, unless I have explicitly tagged that service in my manifest to run under another process.

I find myself mistaken...

For some reason, rarely, I see that another instance of my AIDL service running in another process that is newly created along side the first one.

So at the end I am left with two AIDL services that live in two processes that have two different states.

I had to add a beacon print to monitor this, and indeed log is printed with two states and two process ids.

I should point out we running a custom ROM, that we built from sources, and that this app is running with system permissions.

How do I make Android stop doing that?

Comment: Check the process details for the two processes. If there are multiple users definitely in the device, each will get their own process

Comment: in general, you are correct, however we are running on our custom rom, and pretty sure we have a single user.. will look further into it though.